# SimpleDateFormat parse incorrect time

Tags: java, parsing, timezone

I parse time from string in format "HH:mm" with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. For example `10:30` or `22:10`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date parsed = formatter.parse((String) value);
```

Formatter time zone is default time zone for my device (Moscow time zone +04:00). Time string is `10:30` and
after parsing i expect `10:30 01/01/1970` in moscow time zone but get `09:30 01/01/1970` instead. What i do wrong? Why i getting this behavior?

Comment: `Date`s are very unreliable. Use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), or even better [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to handle dates

Comment: @Keppil It is correct in this case, but you are right that Joda Time is a better choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, didn't have a good answer for this particular case, but just thought I'd mention it to hopefully let OP avoid a lot of future headaches.

Comment: I do not want use additional dependencies in project, therefore Joda Time not suitable.

Not clearly understanding how i can do parsing using Calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1931 to 1981, Moscow was UTC+3. 
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=166&syear=1970

Time-zones change over time, often for political reasons.

Comment: Ok, therefore the reason of this problem is hardcode inside SimpleDateFormat implementation?

Comment: IMHO, The behaviour is correct so there is no problem. Note: before 1930 Moscow was UTC+2. If you want `UTC+4` in all years, you can use this as the timezone.

Comment: Yeah, behaviour is correct, i understand. Thanks, stackoverflowers!